# Angular: passing large text strings between components

Tags: angular, angular-components

(Advanced warning... I am very new to Angular, so my question may be naive and/or not make sense...)

I'm working on an Angular project (v. 5), and I need to pass a long-ish string (a large XML document - about 1mb) from a parent to a child component.

One option to do this is to use an @Input in the child component. I've tested this and it "works", although I don't know if it's a "good idea" for this large an amount of data.

A second option is to use @ViewChild(). E.g.,

In the parent.ts:

```
// set the child component as a @ViewChild
@ViewChild(ChildChartComponent)
private childChartComponent: ChildChartComponent;

// [get the xmlString from a service]
// ... then pass it to the child ...
this.childChartComponent.loadData(xmlString);
```

In the child.ts:

```
loadData(xmlString):void {
  // receive the xmlString, parse it, then extract and display the data
}
```

A few notes...

1. As I mentioned - the XML is pretty large - could be 1mb or more.
2. After the XML data is obtained by the parent, passed to the child, then parsed and processed, there's no need to "maintain" it. (I.e., I'd like it garbage-collected).
3. I don't really know how Angular is working under the hood, or actually passing that data from the parent to the child. But the @INPUT approach makes it look like the string is written as an attribute value:

   `<child-chart [xmlString]="xmlString"></child-chart>`

I suspect that Angular isn't **actually** writing that 1mb string into an attribute property that's bloating the DOM and sitting there after it's now longer needed, but I don't really know...

So - is either one of these methods preferred for passing very long strings? Or is there an altogether different, but preferrable method?

Comment: you are sharing a large data across components correct? use a state management technique

Comment: @Aravind - to be clear - if the user does a certain action - the app needs to fetch a bunch of data from a service (which returns the data in XML format). The parent component (which receives the data), then passes the data to the child component (a charting widget), which parses the XML and displays the data). So - I'm not worried about managing state, and the parent is getting the data successfully. The missing piece is just passing the data from the parent to the child component.

Comment: possible with either `@Input()`, or  `BehaviorSubject` as well.

Comment: Benny - thank you. I've tried using `@Input` - that method works. I'm actually wondering not whether it *works* but whether it is  ***recommended and appropriate*** for such a large amount of data. (In all of the tutorials and examples, I've only seen `@Input` used to pass a numeric value, or a short string.

Comment: i would suggest you to use [shared services](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) in order to pass large amount of data across components

Comment: I think you can make use of BehaviorSubject and share the data by creating a service, to be more clear behavior subject essentially means that you are creating an observable. Observable is designed to tackle this kind of problem. Let me know if you wish to see some codes around it I can create one for you.

Comment: @mattstuehler, you can pass any type of data using `@Input` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned both ways get the job done, But angular is meant to be agnostic. We shouldn't be mixing the role of the view(html) with the controller(components). I would prefer @ViewChild() which gives direct communication from component to component as opposed to going through the DOM to get to a component, for bigger files. You can also access the service directly unless you have a reason to bring the file to component then to the child component.